# How do I map an array of numbers to a property in an array of objects?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to map an array of values to a property in an array of objects.

`var myArray = ['2', '4', '7'];`

```
var myProducts = [
  {id: '755', price: '10'}, 
  {id: '756', price: '20'}, 
  {id: '757', price: '30'}
];
```

Please note that the length of `myArray` will always equal the number of objects in `myProducts`.

My first thought was to loop through objects in `myProducts`, and then mapping `myArray` to the `shipping` property inside that loop:

```
myProducts.forEach(function(obj) {
  obj.shipping = Array.prototype.map(myArray);
});
```

But this isn't working, and I am also now questioning whether I should be using `.map` within the `forEach` loop. What's the best way to do this?

**Desired result**:

```
var myProducts = [
  {id: '755', price: '10', shipping: '2'}, 
  {id: '756', price: '20', shipping: '4'}, 
  {id: '757', price: '30', shipping: '7'}
];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take the index and assign the value to the property

```js
var myArray = ['2', '4', '7'],
    myProducts = [{ id: '755', price: '10' }, { id: '756', price: '20' }, { id: '757', price: '30' }];
    
myProducts.forEach((o, i) => o.shipping = myArray[i]);

console.log(myProducts);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Duplicate of my answer. ES6-y though.

Comment: @ryanpcmcquen, com'on you don't wanna say this.

Comment: @GeorgeBailey, why?

Comment: True, but it was one minute later ... and uses the same `.forEach` idea.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use the second argument of `.forEach(`'s callback, which gives you the index of the iterator:

```js
var myArray = ["2", "4", "7"];

var myProducts = [
    { id: "755", price: "10" },
    { id: "756", price: "20" },
    { id: "757", price: "30" }
];

myProducts.forEach(function(obj, index) {
    obj.shipping = myArray[index];
});

console.log(myProducts);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a regular `for` loop, because you need to keep track of the index.

```js
var myArray = ['2', '4', '7'];
var myProducts = [
  {id: '755', price: '10'}, 
  {id: '756', price: '20'}, 
  {id: '757', price: '30'}
];

for (var i = 0; i < myProducts.length; i++) {
    myProducts[i].shipping = myArray[i];
}

console.log(myProducts);
```

Comment: Native methods are preferred over for loops.

Comment: @ryanpcmcquen Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether you want to mutate that object specifically or if you don't mind creating a new object

Creating a new object

```
newProducts = myProducts.map((product, index ) => {
    product['shipping'] = myArray[index];
    return product;
})
```

Mutating existing object

```
myArray.forEach((item, index) => {
    myProducts[index]['shipping'] = item;
});
```

Creating a new item is useful if you are doing this in a function and don't want to mangle the products array in its original location before you called this since objects are passed by reference.

Answer (score -1):

```
Use index based for each loop iterator

var myArray = ['2', '4', '7'];

var myProducts = [
{ id: '755', price: '10' },
{ id: '756', price: '20' },
{ id: '757', price: '30' },
];

myProducts.forEach(function(obj, index) {
 obj.shipping = myArray[index];
});
```